# Webpack - How to alias dynamically according to file location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a project tree where many subparts that are similar. It looks like this:

```
root
|-- editor
   |- components
   |- services
   |- utils
|-- dashboard
  |- components
  |- services
  |- utils
```

I want to alias `'components'` (for example), to match `editor/components` when the requiring file is inside `editor`, and `dashboard/components` when the requiring file is inside `dashboard`.

Is there a way to do it (resolve dynamically)? Or do I have to assign separate aliases?